# Calling function in bash/Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

When I am calling function in shell script like it's not working

```
testfunction
```

but if I call function like below it's working

```
$(testfunction);
```

Any thoughts? I am running bash shell on Ubuntu

Thank you,
Sambhav

Hi All, Here is a sample script and function decl. and call. As mentioned in the question the funcation call - function is not working but $(function is working)

```
#!/bin/bash 
TITLE=My Title"; 
########FUNCTIONS 
### Function Declaration 
test() { echo "echoing test"; } 
cat << EOF <html> <head> <TITLE>"$TITLE"</TITLE>
</head>
</body> 
### Calling the function here - Not working test 
#### The Below function call is working $(test) 
</body> 
</html> 
EOF
```

Comment: Please show how and where you define the function.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is the worst possible description. What does happen? What do you expect to happen? How are the answers different?

Comment: More importantly actually is that you show your error messages.

Comment: You cannot add a statement inside a "here-document". Everything between <<EOF and EOF is a string which gets expanded. So you can only use variables or other expressions (like $()).

Comment: @Sambhav You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25214897/edit) your post.

Comment: Thanks Konsolebox, I will keep in mind for sure from the next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(cmd)` expands to a string with the result of the cmd executed. It is not often used with functions, but it can be. See this illustration which invokes the function in both styles:

```
$ cat sample.sh
#!/bin/sh
bla() {
  echo something
}
# print something
bla
# record something
BLA=$(bla)
echo recorded: $BLA
###
$ ./sample.sh
something
recorded: something
```

Following up on your comment, your problem seems to be the "here document" used with `<<`. A here document is basically a multi-line string:

```
echo "this is a string, bla is not recognized as a function"
echo "this is a string, $(bla) executes the function and replaces the output"
cat << EOF
Multi Line
$(bla)
Document
EOF
```

Alternatively you can end the here document:

```
cat << EOF1
<html><header><titl
<title>test</title></header>
<body>
EOF1
# this section is script code, not here-document
bla
#
cat << EOF2
</body></html>
EOF2
```

Comment: please add it to your question, then you can format it readable.

Comment: Typo: `${bla]` should be `$(bla)` - mine too

Comment: Great, Thanks eckes....
About the suggestion for editing the question instead of comment, I will keep in mind from the next time. 

Best Regards,
Sambhav